# Парсер сайта на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
type(browser)
browser.get('https://www.housebrand.com/ru/ru/')
total_phone = []

phone = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('price')
total_phone.append(phone)
print(total_phone)
```

Я новичок в питоне, но пришлось написать собственный парсер, почему у меня не получается спарсить класс "price"?

Вот результат выполнения скрипта:

*C:\Users\ivan-x\PycharmProjects\AutomationOfRoutineTasks\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/ivan-x/PycharmProjects/AutomationOfRoutineTasks/webapp/prg.py
[[<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="850bc1ce-4474-4a08-b833-3828d86f122b", element="360fa872-6dea-4aee-a505-8be66ed46fd3")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="850bc1ce-4474-4a08-b833-3828d86f122b", element="3d464beb-5c15-413f-bf74-45de3d472dfa")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="850bc1ce-4474-4a08-b833-3828d86f122b", element="53f3b724-d74e-4320-ac31-d934cf9b3541")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="850bc1ce-4474-4a08-b833-3828d86f122b", element="3d359089-7f3e-42fe-9db7-3e5ee9644fdd")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="850bc1ce-4474-4a08-b833-3828d86f122b", element="07931de8-6fec-4ec3-9065-a6573fea2d51")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="850bc1ce-4474-4a08-b833-3828d86f122b", element="8f0933a5-61a3-45e4-a116-9ba044a5a4a6")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="850bc1ce-4474-4a08-b833-3828d86f122b", element="d62b48a8-e6a1-44c7-ad02-f44490824847")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="850bc1ce-4474-4a08-b833-3828d86f122b", element="cef45827-60b5-4d1c-af6d-0f81b5c27c40")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="850bc1ce-4474-4a08-b833-3828d86f122b", element="49925f0e-f655-4695-b6a9-3618555a37bb")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="850bc1ce-4474-4a08-b833-3828d86f122b", element="4bc89032-5344-45d4-9490-ad9050e164d7")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="850bc1ce-4474-4a08-b833-3828d86f122b", element="9cfc9b6b-4451-4799-96bc-3f880edb101a")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="850bc1ce-4474-4a08-b833-3828d86f122b", element="c384cd65-8b6e-4598-b3fc-311d64242595")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="850bc1ce-4474-4a08-b833-3828d86f122b", element="30a5157d-dbaa-46b0-8b07-fcc278c47d1b")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="850bc1ce-4474-4a08-b833-3828d86f122b", element="f37d7f0e-850a-4a19-94ef-51dae0ef6355")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="850bc1ce-4474-4a08-b833-3828d86f122b", element="4bffc11f-1b80-4515-9c34-48c74dd1a331")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="850bc1ce-4474-4a08-b833-3828d86f122b", element="ca85c9d2-aab3-45bd-99d9-4994ec7a08ef")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="850bc1ce-4474-4a08-b833-3828d86f122b", element="03c0f479-243f-4f6f-8bfb-acdc3666371b")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="850bc1ce-4474-4a08-b833-3828d86f122b", element="26507ba4-3f41-45e1-9b07-3404fd6df124")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="850bc1ce-4474-4a08-b833-3828d86f122b", element="9a4d59b4-ae38-4d20-8d04-1bdf15fdbb92")>]]

Process finished with exit code 0*

Как заставить его выдавать список элементов из class='price'?
Почему данные сохраняются в таком формате? Этот элементы должен отображаться как цены на заданной странице.
Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Переходим сюда [selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.html#WebElement.find_element_by_class_name) и наблюдаем, что ниже существует еще один метод: `find_elements_by_class_name` (elementS). Если я правильно **угадал** вашу проблему, то используйте `find_elements_by_class_name`, а не `find_element_by_class_name`.

Comment: спасибо за помощь, теперь сохраняется не один элемент, а все, но при этом я не понимаю почему в таком формате? На месте этих длинных идентификаторов я ожидал увидеть цены на товары, которые расположены на заданной странице. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вам следует хоть базово узнать, что такое XML разметка. Эти парсеры - обертки для ее обработки. Они дают вам класс - вы интерпретируете его как данные. Предоставьте больше информации по виду элемента с классом price (из браузера скопируйте что-ли).